# how to assign a requestMapping dynamically

Tags: java, spring

Is it possible to change the RequestMapping values dynamically ?

For Example,

```
@RequestMapping("Example.do")
public void example(){

}
```

I need to have something like follow

```
@RequestMapping("Example.*")
public void example(){

}
```

Where I can replace the * dynamically by configure in either applicationContext.xml or web.xml, Say if I replace (*)  to (htm) everywhere it should replace with the ".htm" like

```
@RequestMapping("Example.htm")
public void example(){

}
```

Plz let me know if possible.

Comment: I don't think it is possible (I'm saying "think" because negative answers require such a certainty..). But you do know you can use `@RequestMapping("Example.*")` and have a logic inside `example()` that  could deal with the content of `*`, right?

Comment: Actually I have created some custom jar with @RequestMapping("Example.do").

Comment: i need that jar to be generic so that it can use in any application.Here the problem is, if any application uses the .htm then the jar function's are not mapping.

Comment: It is possible to use `@RequestMapping("Example.XXX")` or `@RequestMapping("Example.YYY")` or `@RequestMapping("Example.*")`. What I said is not possible is to use is something like `@RequestMapping("Example.#{variableThatWillBeDefinedAtTheApplicationContext}")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
@RequestMapping("Example.{extension}")
public example ( @PathVariable String extension ) {
    //logic
}
```

Comment: Thanks darijan : Let me try with this

Comment: Where should I inject that {extension} ?

Comment: Well, depending on the request parameter, whatever comes in ("do", "htm", or something third) in the code you decide what to do with it.